# Get reverse relation in Django Serializer

Tags: django, django-models, django-rest-framework, django-queryset

Models:

```
class MaterialRequest(models.Model):

    owner = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='owner')
    linked = models.CharField(max_length=50, default="-", blank=True, null=True)
    flows = models.ManyToManyField(MaterialRequestFlow)
    is_allocated = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    delivery_required_on = models.DateTimeField(default=datetime.now)
    raised_by = models.CharField(max_length=1000, default="__________", blank=True, null=True)
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)

class Allotment(models.Model):

    transaction_no = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    sales_order = models.ForeignKey(MaterialRequest, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    is_delivered = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    document_available = models.BooleanField(default=False)
```

Now to show my Material Request table I am doing something like this:

```
class MREmpTableAPIView(APIView):
    permission_classes = (permissions.IsAuthenticated, MRViewPermission)

    def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        items = MaterialRequest.objects.all().order_by('-id')
        serializer = EMaterialRequestTableListSerializer(items, many=True)
        return Response(serializer.data, status=status.HTTP_201_CREATED)
```

Serializer:

```
class EMaterialRequestTableListSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    owner = serializers.SlugRelatedField(read_only=True, slug_field='full_name')

    class Meta:
        model = MaterialRequest
        exclude = ('flows',)
```

Where I get all the detaila of Material Requests but I also want to show the `transaction_no` of the `linked` Allotment in Material Request Table. How do I do that?

Edit:

A single Material Request is linked with a single allotment(transaction_no), I want to show the `Transaction no` on the same table

Output I am getting:

```
created_at: "2021-09-22T10:28:44.248034Z"
delivery_required_on: "2021-09-22T09:08:43.968000Z"
id: 739
is_allocated: false
linked: "729-3"
owner: "Lumax Mannoh Allied Technologies Limited"
```

Desired Output:

```
created_at: "2021-09-22T10:28:44.248034Z"
delivery_required_on: "2021-09-22T09:08:43.968000Z"
id: 739
is_allocated: false
linked: "729-3"
owner: "Lumax Mannoh Allied Technologies Limited"
transaction_no: foo
```

Comment: Can you share your serializer? Which of the `Allotment` `transaction_no` of a `MaterialRequest` do you need? All of them?

Comment: @BrianD I have updated the question with serializer, I want to show the `transacation_no` of every Material Request

Comment: OK each material request can have multiple `Allotment`s so you will end up with a list of transaction numbers. Can you share a sample output you were looking for?

Comment: @BrianD In that case I would like to have the first element of the list, the code generally prevents the user from creating allotment if one already exists.. so that might not be the problem

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A straightforward way to solve this is to use a `SerializerMethodField` like this:

```
class EMaterialRequestTableListSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    owner = serializers.SlugRelatedField(read_only=True, slug_field='full_name')
    transaction_no = serializers.SerializerMethodField()

    class Meta:
        model = MaterialRequest
        exclude = ('flows',)

    def get_transaction_no(self, obj)
        allotment = obj.allotment_set.first()
        return allotment.transaction_no if allotment else None
```

But this will try to hit the database per `MaterialRequest` instance just to get the related allotments.

To make this more efficient, you can prefetch the related allotments of each material request like this:

```
items = MaterialRequest.objects.all().order_by('-id').prefetch_related('allotment_set')
```

And then do something like this in your serializer:

```
class EMaterialRequestTableListSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    owner = serializers.SlugRelatedField(read_only=True, slug_field='full_name')
    transaction_no = serializers.SerializerMethodField()

    class Meta:
        model = MaterialRequest
        exclude = ('flows',)

    def get_transaction_no(self, obj)
        if obj.allotment_set.all():
            return obj.allotment_set.all()[0].transaction_no
        return None
```